# List with people; create a per-person view

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list with everyone's responsibilities (so this is not a task list that can be checked off).
I assigned one or more people to it with a people column.

Is it possible to get an overview of the records assigned to a person?
Thinking about databases; I'm not sure this is possible.

*fe. if I click on Josh, I retrieve a list of all records where josh is tagged.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the filter in the list to return all records marked with a specific person.

[image]

If you want to view the records of other users, just change the filter.

In addition, you can also save the filtered view as a new view.

Comment: Sometimes a person can search for such a complicated solution eventhough there's an easy one.  
Thank you